# Gradient system with respect to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $L^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+\cos u -1 +\mu.~~(1)
$$

I have two questions:

(I.) Can we write PDE (1) as
$$
u_t=-\text{grad} V(u),
$$
i.e. is it a gradient system with respect to the standard scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^n$, say $n=1$ and $u_t=-V'(u)$

(II.) Can (1) it be written as
$$
u_t=-\nabla_{L^2}E(u)
$$
for some functional $E(u)$ and with respect to $L^2$ and the inner product of $L^2$?

My suggestion would be
$$
E(u):=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{2}(u_x)^2+F(u)\, dx,~~F'(u)=-\cos u+1-\mu.
$$

The idea behind this was
$$
\langle\nabla_{L^2} E(u),v\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}} u_xv_x+F'(u)v\, dx.
$$

Moreover, my idea was that by integration by parts
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} u_xv_x\, dx = u_x v-\int_{\mathbb{R}} u_{xx}v\, dx.
$$
Is it reasonable to assume that $u_xv=0$? Because if yes, we would have that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} u_xv_x+F'(u)v\, dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}} (-u_{xx}+F'(u))v\, dx=\langle -u_{xx}+F'(u),v\rangle_{L^2},
$$
hence
$$
\nabla_{L^2}E(u)=-u_{xx}+F'(u)=-u_{xx}-\cos u+1-\mu
$$
and thus
$$
u_t=-\nabla_{L^2} E(u).
$$

Comment: what is $V(u)$?

Comment: Isn't it a potential?

Comment: Does the Laplace equation apply for the potential function? i.e. $v_{xx}+v_{tt}=0$

Comment: @polfosol Why is that important?

Comment: Because that's the definition of a _potential function_